# Laplace equation in a domain with a hole

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I want to know if there is some reference on the well-posedness of the following problem :

For $\Omega$ a bounded domain (what results depending on the regularity of the domain?)   of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$, even $\mathbb{R}^n$), containing a hole, i.e. $\Omega$ has an "interior" boundary $\Gamma_1$ and an "exterior" boundary $\Gamma_2$, we look for the solution of :

1. $\Delta u=0$ (harmonic function)
2. $u=g_1$ on $\Gamma_1$
3. $u=g_2$ on $\Gamma_2$

Some theorem, paper, or book that treats this question? Maybe the answer exists even for more general elliptic equations (maybe with a uniform ellipticity hypothesis?)

Also, I guess the results may depend on some "topological" property in the case of arbitrary spatial dimension $n$.

I guess the results also may depend strongly on the regularity of the domain.

Comment: This is the [Dirichlet problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem). The case for dimension two is frequently treated in books on complex analysis.

Comment: Thank you, Massimo, but I think actually it is different... there are 2 boundaries so two functions are defined on $\partial \Omega=\Gamma_1 \cup\Gamma_2$

Comment: There aren’t two boundaries: there is one boundary with two connected components. It’s still a Dirichlet problem.